# How to sync products to local sql database for on-premise app

Tags: mysql, database, shopify, offline

I’ m currently developing a on-premise app for a local business.

The point of this app is to manage the cashing system and get input from a barcode scanner.

When a barcode is scanned the app should make a request to Shopify to get the product to display  it in my app and adjust the stock value. I can do this by using the admin api.

But this is not a great solution when the internet is down. Then I cannot request for products.

Therefore I need to request all products periodically to store it locally and use the local db to make changes and when the internet is back update to shopify.

But when I do this a new problem arises. For example, I request at 9:00AM all the products,

If a client comes to the local store and buys an item its stock value is : stock - 1. But when another client goes to our online store and buys the same item, the stock will get adjusted to. The problem is when the product is on stock value 1.

When I do a resync later eg (1:PM) the total stock of the product will get -1, which is not a valid stock and someone bought a product that is no longer in stock.

Is there a reliable way to sync shopify products to a local db and keep the stock updated at all times ?

Kind regards

Jens Vanhulst

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm planning to use MySql

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Without further details, this is nearly impossible to be answered

Comment: As stated in the description I tried to sync it with periodically requesting the products via the admin api

Comment: But I can’t send a request every second to update every product in the db

Comment: I’m asking if anyone has a better solution to sync products from shopify to a local db

Comment: Send a request to your server after scanning an article. The response should contain the current stock for the article scanned.

Comment: @Luuk yea I did that. But when the internet fails I can’t request products. Thats why I need a local db

Comment: Then 'reserve' some of your stock for local sale. i.e. If you have 10 pieces on stock, and reserve 2 for local sale, The internet (Shopify) should show 8. After selling 2 pieces locally a resync is needed.